# Recurrency is ok but if part is complicated

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many subsets does the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ have that contain no two
consecutive integers if $1$ and $n$ also count as consecutive?

Comment: Remark: this is equivalent to counting the number of independent sets of the cycle graph $C_n$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the title?  What is the "recurrency" and "if part"?

Comment: It is http://oeis.org/A169985, the nearest integer to $\phi^n$, but no derivation is given.

Comment: @RossMillikan The $n^\text{th}$ Fibonacci number is the nearest integer to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$: cf. [Wilf](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf), p. 10.

Comment: @SpamIAm:  I am aware of that.  These are not the Fibonacci numbers because of the restriction on $1,n$

Answer (score 1):

If you take a (numbered) $n\times1$ strip and count the number of ways to tile it with squares and dominoes, you get the standard Fibonacci numbers.  If you wrap the strip around into a circle and do the same, then, except when $n=1$, you get the sequence [A169985](http://oeis.org/A169985) that Ross Millikan noted in comments.  For $n\not=1$, there is a one-to-one correspondence between tilings and subsets with no consecutive numbers:  for each domino in a tiling, let the subset include the smaller of the two numbers covered by the domino (where $n$ is considered "smaller" than $1$), and vice versa.

The case $n=1$ is special in that the only way to tile a $1\times1$ wrap-around strip is with a square, but there are obviously two subsets satisfying the non-consecutivity condition, $\emptyset$ and $\{1\}$.

(The case $n=2$ might also be considered special, depending on how you count the number ways to place the domino.  I'm viewing it as having two options.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to compute this.

Let $X_n$ be the number of independent sets of a simple path on $n$ vertices.  For $n=0$, the only independent set is the empty set, so $X_0=1$. For convenience, we define $X_n = 1$ for $n<0$ as well.  For $n>0$, either we include the first vertex and exclude the second, leaving $n-2$ vertices, or we exclude the first vertex, leaving $n-1$ vertices.  This gives us:
$$
X_n = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & n \leq 0 \\
X_{n-2} + X_{n-1} & n \gt 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Let $Y_n$ be the number of independent sets of a simple cycle on $n>0$ vertices.  Designate some "starting vertex".  Then we either include the starting vertex (leaving a path of $n-3$ vertices), or we don't (leaving a path of $n-1$ vertices).  So: $$Y_n = X_{n-3} + X_{n-1}$$

**Edit:**  Wow, I just noticed that for $n\geq-1$, $X_n$ is in fact the $(n+1)$<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number!  That probably explains the relation to $\phi$ on OEIS.

Comment: The series starts $1,2,3,4,7,11,18$, which are not the Fibonacci numbers.  The problem is that for $n=3$ we do not permit ${1,3}$ as a subset.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, the terms of the sequence $Y_n = X_{n-3}+X_{n-1} = F_{n-2} + F_{n}$ are not themselves Fibonacci numbers.